# Gradle not working whatsoever in Gradle project

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I am on Ubuntu Linux and trying to run Gradle in a Gradle project that I received from my professor. I have Gradle and Java installed, with Java being version 21.0.2 and Gradle being version 4.4.1. When I attempt to run any command beginning with `gradle`, it outputs this:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().
> Could not create service of type PluginResolutionStrategyInternal using BuildScopeServices.createPluginResolutionStrategy().
```

I have heard trying a wrapper, but I cannot make one as generating one requires `gradle` to work.
I know it is not the fault of the professor, as on another machine `gradle` commands work just fine.

Here is the `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
        id 'java'
}

repositories {
        mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
        testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.6.0')
}

test {
        useJUnitPlatform()
        testLogging {
                events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
        }
}
```

Any support is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Gradle 4.4.1 is very old. Try a newer version; the latest as of this comment is 8.5 (which, by the way, is the first version to officially support [_running_ on Java 21](https://docs.gradle.org/8.5/release-notes.html#full-java-21-support)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Gradle version seems not compatible with Java version try using Gradle v8.5 as example : https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html